# MacPro after wake-up takes ages before Wi-Fi connects?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, mac-pro

Basically once my MacPro wakes up, the Wi-Fi icon is greyed out and it takes like a minute (which feels pretty long), before it connects to my home Wi-Fi network.

This happened already a few times over the last year. It starts happening without a good reason, and it fixes itself also like that. Utterly annoying.

I cleaned up my Wi-Fi list (only 3 networks in it) and my home network is on the top.

Running 10.13.3

Any clues?

Comment: It probably the Wi-Fi adapter.  There's nothing in settings that would cause something to "be slow" in coming alive; it's either on or not.

Comment: Is it only on a specific wifi network that this happens or does it happen on any network?

Comment: How many Wi-Fi networks are there in the drop down Wi-Fi menu from the menu bar?

Comment: Yeah quite a lot. There like 20+. Maybe it’s channel issues. Problem is I kind reproduce it. Sometimes happens.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to delete your wifi settings?

- Go go to System Preferences > Network > Use the (-) to delete wifi. Use the (+) to add a new wifi setting.
  Do you use additional network settings e.g. Ethernet or iPhone USB? If so, try to disable them or set the Service Order accordingly.
- It could be a network issue. Maybe your wifi DHCP Server is slowing things done.